# Traverse/Rewrite a JSON Value

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have the following json-data

```
value :: Maybe Value
value = decode
    "{ \"import\"  : { \"starttime\": \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"endtime\"  : \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ } \
   \ , \"export\"  : { \"starttime\": \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"endtime\"  : \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ } \
   \ , \"cleanup\" : { \"starttime\": \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"endtime\"  : \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"errormsg\" : \"It is dead Jim!\" \
                   \ } \
   \ }"
```

and my goal would be to rewrite this object such that it only contains the "direct path" to a given key - e.g. if I search for "errormsg" it should only be

```
Just "{\"cleanup\":\"It is dead Jim!\"}"
```

or

```
Just "{\"cleanup\": {\"errormsg\":\"It is dead Jim!\"}}"
```

and `Nothing` in the case where the key is not present, my knowledge about Prisms and Traversals is still in the stage of development so the only thing I managed to do is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack runhaskell --package=lens --package=aeson --package=lens-aeson-lens --package=bytestring
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

value :: Maybe Value
value = decode
    "{ \"import\"  : { \"starttime\": \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"endtime\"  : \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ } \
   \ , \"export\"  : { \"starttime\": \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"endtime\"  : \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ } \
   \ , \"cleanup\" : { \"starttime\": \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"endtime\"  : \"2017-02-20T18:45:456.45645\" \
                   \ , \"errormsg\" : \"It is dead Jim!\" \
                   \ } \
   \ }"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  traverse_ (traverse (B.putStrLn . encode))
            [ value & _Just . members %~ fromMaybe Null . preview (key "errormsg")
            , value & _Just . members %~ fromMaybe Null . preview (key "not here")
            ]
```

which yields

```
{"export":null,"cleanup":"It is dead Jim!","import":null}
{"export":null,"cleanup":null,"import":null}
```

Comment: You might find this a bit easier with an adjustment to the problem. Rather than returning a whole JSON blob which has been filtered, try returning the two pieces: `data Result = Result { path :: [String], piece :: Value }`. You can then straightforwardly rebuild a whole JSON value from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Benjamin Hodgson's idea of having a separate data type for paths, here's a possible solution which uses *lens-aeson* and `Control.Lens.Plated`:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Plated (para)
import Data.Foldable (asum)
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Text (Text)

data JsonPathPiece = Key Text | Index Int deriving Show

data JsonPath = JsonPath [JsonPathPiece] Value deriving Show

path :: Text -> Value -> Maybe JsonPath
path key = para go
    where
    go :: Value -> [Maybe JsonPath] -> Maybe JsonPath
    go v previous = case v of
        Object o  -> asum $ keyFound o : zipIntoMaybes Key o previous
        Array as  -> asum $ zipIntoMaybes Index as previous
        _         -> Nothing
    keyFound = preview (ix key.to (JsonPath [Key key]))
    zipIntoMaybes makePiece as mbs =
        zipWith fmap (toListOf (ifolded.asIndex.to makePiece.to addPiece) as) mbs
    addPiece piece (JsonPath pieces v) = JsonPath (piece:pieces) v
```

[`para`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:para) is a paramorphism that "destroys" a `Value` starting form the leaves. When processing each node, we have access to the results obtained for its children.

[`asum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) for `Maybe`returns the first `Just` from the left.

[`ifolded.asIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:ifolded) produces the list of keys of a map, or the list of integer indices for a vector. They are matched one for one with the results for the children of the current node.